# Strange name after storing date into firebase

Tags: json, angular, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone told me why my json looks like this [image]

instead without this strange name started with -M-yv...

I'm storing my data just using http.post method passing url to my database and object to save by calling arrayName.slice().
Is it default behavior for the firebase?

Comment: It's a unique key generated by Firebase, it's standard. You can choose to store it with your own key if you have to.

Comment: Can you tell where should i find this configuration? I know, read documentation ;D

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... i'm used put instead post and problem is solved.